# $.makeArray() on "real" arrays and primitive data types

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently, I'm doing something like this:

```
var foo = $.isArray(bar) ? bar : [bar];
```

Where `bar` can be either an array e.g. `[1,2,3]` or a number, like `1`.

[$.makeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.makearray/) crossed my mind, but it seems like it's intended to be used on objects with an array-like structure (like the jQuery object), to make use of an array's built-in methods that normally wouldn't exist on the object.

```
var foo = $.makeArray(bar);

console.log( $.makeArray(1), $.makeArray([1]) ); // [1], [1]
```

The above code seems to work fine, but what I'm wonder is if it just happens to work (and therefore isn't safe to rely on) or if this is a valid use-case for `makeArray()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you *know* that it's *only* either a primitive number or an array, this is a perfectly valid usecase (even if it's undocumented).

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do `$.makeArray(1)` because according to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.makearray/) this is a function for 'array like' objects, this would be a node list (returned by `document.getElementsByTagName`) or an `arguments` array like object within a function.

It will work today and probably in the near future, but jQuery can change the implementation any time to align more appropriately with their spec.